# I replaced a 3-way and an ordinary switch and now my breaker won’t untrip

Tags: electrical, lighting, electrical-panel

I am a new homeowner completing renos on my house. There were already several major structural issues we corrected that were due to builder negligence. This post is regarding a set of light switches I have changed out, which now cause the breaker to remain tripped.

The box has 3 switches as follows:

- Switch 1. A 3-way switch on breaker A
- Switch 2. A regular switch on breaker A
- Switch 3. A 3-way switch on breaker B

When I initially swapped out all the switches and turned back on the power, all 3 worked. I flipped the lights on and off, then went to go check the alternate switch for switch 1. When I returned the light was no longer on and breaker A had tripped. Breaker B is working. Breaker A stays tripped after I reset it and I’m not sure what the problem is.

The wires on switch 1 & 2 were not colour coded, so there’s a chance I could’ve mixed those up during the swap. But the wires I have connected as the hot wires splice together with two other wires that come out of the box from different points.

Any advice or recomended troubleshooting is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Have you considered whether breaker A is actually tripping instantly when turned on? You could disconnect the wire from breaker A's terminal and then check whether the breaker can be reset properly.

Comment: For the name of all that is holy, _**PLEASE**_ do away with that taped splice joint on switch 1!!! That violates code and it's probably a good thing your breaker is tripping preventing that loose joint from heating and catching fire. Simply attach the wire coming from the wall directly to the switch, or use a wire nut. Just tape is _NOT_ enough for a splice!

Comment: Also "3-way switch" is, most likely, the key to the problem. The wires attach to the switch based on the color of the screws, not on the positions. Different manufacturers will put the different screws in different physical positions. The same manufacturer might even switch things up within different products in their lineup. Having the white wire (which _most likely_ is neutral) connected to S1 and S3 is probably wrong.

Comment: Oh that tape is just a temporary label from when I disconnected it haha not a splice. 

I found out that it is not supposed to be a 3 way switch - the prev switch on S1 was programmable so it had a neutral going to it which is not needed anymore. It was causing the short

Comment: You couldn't tell whether a wire is a neutral? You may need to properly label them so the next guy doesn't repeat the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

disconnect one switch at a time, starting with the 3-way switch, until breaker A can close and not open; if I interpret your description correctly that with all 3 switches and regardless of the on/off position of the 3-way switch that breaker A trips as soon as you close it at the panel... so you have something mis-wired and a hot going to neutral.  With all 3 switches disconnected if the breaker still will not close then you have a hot to neutral/ground touching somewhere.  Based on what you've described and done (or not done) so far... you sorta don't know what you are doing.

your bias on the builder (and negligence there whether true or not) is clouding your rationale and judgement on this electrical issue.

Answer (score 1):

At S1 and S3 it looks like you have white wires attached to the switches.  This is wrong for several reasons.

The very first thing you should do is turn off **both** circuit breakers.

Then, detach and insulate those white wires so they are not touching anything.

After that, try resetting the breakers one at a time.

If there's still a problem, then you will need to remove all three switches and work on correctly identifying the grounded and non-grounded conductors.